# How is אנדרוגינוס/Androgynus possible?

Tags: men-male, androgynous

I was wondering, how is the case of אנדרוגינוס possible. Isn't the person a   male if he has the אבר המין הזכרי?

Comment: As above it is when instead of testicals he has a vagina

Answer (score 1):

According to Rambam and the Shulchan Aruch the status of an androgynous is *safek*, so we cannot be sure whether the case involves a male or a female:

[Mishne Torah (Ishut 2:24)](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=4&hilchos=22&perek=2&halocha=24&hilite=):

> כד. מי שיש לו אבר זכרות ואבר נקבות הוא הנקרא אנדרוגינוס והוא ספק אם
>   זכר ספק אם נקבה. ואין לו סימן שיודע בו אם הוא זכר ודאי אם היא נקבה
>   ודאית לעולם:

[Shulchan Aruch YD 194:8](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01976_part_29.html):

> ח הַיּוֹלֶדֶת טֻמְטוּם אוֹ אַנְדְּרוֹגִינוּס, נוֹתְנִין לָהּ יְמֵי
>   טֻמְאָה שֶׁל נְקֵבָה.

[Shulchan Aruch YD 315:3](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01976_part_51.html?dyn#HtmpReportNum0009_L2):

> ג אַנְדְּרוֹגִינוּס הוּא סָפֵק בְּכוֹר, וְיֵאָכֵל בְּמוּמוֹ
>   לַבְּעָלִים.

However in [Avodas Kochavim in Perek 12](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?mfid=47651&rid=376) there is the following halacha:

> ד. טומטום ואנדרוגינוס הרי הן ספק נותנין עליהן חומרי האיש וחומרי האשה
>   בכל מקום וחייבים בכל ואם עברו אינם לוקין:

Hope that helps :)

Comment: It does , thank you! I know I'm taking this to a deeper level , but for what reason would  ה' create an Androgynus (are there any sources to explain this)?

Comment: By the same reason that He created Adam. BTW, there is an opinion in midrash that says בשעה שברא הקדוש ברוך הוא את אדם הראשון אנדרוגינוס בראו

Comment: Let me ask my question differently. Why would ה׳ create an Androgynus rather than create a male or female instead. Does it maybe have to do with "Gillgulim"?

Comment: @sye81397 to add  Shulcjan aruch harav 199.8 androginus are  either all men or all woman, not that each one is a sofik separately

Comment: @sye81397, perhaps you may ask this on separate question